# Como a função include do PHP funciona por trás dos panos

Tags: php, include, serialização

Digamos que eu tenha duas páginas, uma chamada `teste.php` e a outra `teste2.php`.

Na página `teste.php` eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
...
$usuario = new Usuario();
$usuarios = $usuario->getUsuarios();
...
```

E na página `teste2.php` tenho o código:

```
...
include "teste.php";
...
```

Ao fazer o include da página `teste.php` na página `teste2.php` qual processo ocorre por trás disso? O php serializa o OBJ da página `teste.php` e ao fazer o include ele usa a function unserialize() nesse OBJ por trás dos panos?

Answer (score 0):

Não há serialização de objetos quando está usando `include`. Porém, o PHP *processa* o arquivo e da a ele um escopo específico, dependendo de **onde** inclui o outro artigo.

A documentação explica bastante sobre como o `include` funciona, os escopos diferentes, etc.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php

Comment: Eu cheguei a olhar a documentação. Mas eu acredito que ela esteja incompleta. Pq o programa Burp Suite está alertando para 'Serialized object in HTTP message' justamente em um arquivo q faz include de outro q estancia um OBJ. :/